# How to remove duplicate lines inside a text file & get the number of the removed lines?

Tags: text-processing, data, duplicate

I know that with

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' filename > output.txt
```

it is possible to remove all duplicates from a text file.But how could I get a list of the removed lines in order to use this information to remove the same lines in another file.

I need this, because I want to remove all duplicates in a large textfile written in one  language and then remove the same lines in the file with the translation of this language without losing the matching of the translation.

To make it more clear: (file 1)

```
line A
line B
line A
line C
...
```

(file 2):

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
...
```

Remove "line A" from file 1 and remove "line 3" from file 2.
Needed for translation:

```
line A -> line 1
line B -> line 2
line C -> line 4
...
```

file 1B (with removed duplicates) would then look like:

```
line A
line B
line C
...
```

file 2B (with removed duplicates) would then look like:

```
line 1
line 2
line 4
...
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicated lines in the second file by _contents_ ("the line saying `hello` is duplicated in the 1st file so remove all lines that are `hello` in the 2nd file") or by _position_ ("line 2 is duplicated in the 1st file, so remove line 2 in the 2nd file")?

Comment: Ah, by position. Good.

Comment: yes, by position

Comment: What is the output? Two new files?

Comment: yes, like described above (new edit)

Comment: it doesn't need to be in one step. I could also write a script using the list of indices to remove the lines in the second file. But if it is possible to do it in the command line, would be better., of course ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR && !seen[$0]++ { keep[FNR]=$0; next } (FNR in keep) { printf("%s -> %s\n", keep[FNR], $0) }' file1 file2
line A -> line 1
line B -> line 2
line C -> line 4
```

This reproduces the output in the middle of the question with an `awk` program.

The program reads the first file (`file1`) and finds the duplicated lines in the first block.  That block also saves the lines to keep in the array `keep`, indexed by line number.

When reading the second file (the second block in the code), if the line number is one that we'd like to keep, output the saved line from the first file together with the line from the second file.

Variation that saves two new files:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && !seen[$0]++ { keep[FNR]=$0; print >FILENAME ".new"; next } (FNR in keep) { print >FILENAME ".new" }' file1 file2
```

This will write `file1.new` with only the unique lines in `file1`, and it will write `file2.new` with the same lines, but from `file2`.

The only downside with this solution is that it requires 2`x` memory, where `x` is the number of unique lines in the first file, i.e., it will store two copies of each unique line in `file1` (as an index in `seen` and as values in the `keep` array).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2 step process:

1. an awk script to generate a sed script to delete the unwanted lines

   ```
   awk 'seen[$0]++ {print NR "d"}' file1 > remove.sed
   ```
2. then use the sed script to remove the lines in the needed files

   ```
   sed -i -f remove.sed file1 file2
   ```